# TypeError when trying to connect with Twitter API Python

Tags: python, typeerror, tweepy, twython

I am trying to post a twitter status update through the python API. My code is the following:

```
consumer_key = "XXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
access_token = "YYYYYYYY"
access_token_secret = "YYYYYYYYY"

import tweepy

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status("Hello this is a test")
```

I always get the following error message:

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

I tried using Twython too but got the same error message (from auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)). Couldn't find anything that helped me online either. Does someone know how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:
After upgrading some packages and restarting the editor a few times it somehow works now. No idea what changed though

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again ? 